# webRTCアプリがHeroku上で動作しない（simple-peer、socket.io）

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io, webrtc

ローカルでは動作するwebRTCアプリがHeroku上では動作せず困ってます。

My Heroku App: https://rgvc-client.herokuapp.com/

Github client: https://github.com/sayagit/RGVC-client

Github server: https://github.com/sayagit/RGVC-server

やりたいこと：
このページに入り、「Create Room」ボタンをクリックすると、動画と音声がブラウザ上で再生されます。その後、アドレスをコピーして、新しいブラウザに貼り付けて移動すると、2つのブラウザ間でビデオチャットが始まります。

問題：
１つ目の動画は起動できますが、新しいブラウザ側の動画が起動できません。エラーも発生してないので原因が分かりません。

※
.envファイルのkeyは、server側は`CLIENT_URL=https://rgvc-client.herokuapp.com/`
client側は`REACT_APP_API=https://rgvc-server.herokuapp.com/`としています。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えてください。